# An Error comes out in func imagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Code:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var myViewController: UIViewController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //ViewControllerのインスタンス化
    myViewController = ViewController()

    //UINavigationControllerのインスタンス化とrootViewControllerの指定
    var myNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myViewController!)

    //UIWindowのインスタンス化
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    //UIWindowのrootViewControllerにnavigationControllerを指定
    self.window?.rootViewController = myNavigationController

    //UIWindowの表示
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true

}
```

}

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

var myImagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
var myImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Select a Image"

    myImageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)

    // インスタンス生成
    myImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    // デリゲート設定
    myImagePicker.delegate = self

    // 画像の取得先はフォトライブラリ
    myImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

    // 画像取得後の編集を不可に
    myImagePicker.allowsEditing = false
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.presentViewController(myImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

/**
 画像が選択された時に呼ばれる.
 */
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    //選択された画像を取得.
    var myImage: AnyObject?  = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]

    //選択された画像を表示するViewControllerを生成.
    let secondViewController = SecondViewController()

    //選択された画像を表示するViewContorllerにセットする.
    secondViewController.mySelectedImage = myImage as! UIImage

    myImagePicker.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

}

/**
 画像選択がキャンセルされた時に呼ばれる.
 */
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {

    // モーダルビューを閉じる
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

**View2.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var mySelectedImage: UIImage!
var mySelectedImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    setImage()
}

/**
 選択された画像をUIImageViewにセットする.
 */
func setImage(){
    self.title = "Selected Image"

    mySelectedImageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    mySelectedImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    mySelectedImageView.image = mySelectedImage
    self.view.addSubview(mySelectedImageView)
}
```

}

In **ViewController.swift**, I get the following error:

> "Objective-C method 'imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:'provided by method 'imagePickerController(*didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)'conflicts with optional requirement method 'imagePickerController(*:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)'in protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'"

What should I do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code use  **String**  insted of  **NSObject**

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
//write code here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to dismiss  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo .

Then viewWillAppear will be called there you can use push viewcontroller .
As presentViewController is not using the present navigation controller so it will not be able to push the viewcontroller